# How to remove .class1, .class2, ... or classN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass

we have this classnames

```
.lightbox620
.lightbox400
..
.lightbox200
```

That we apply to the body page and it determines its width...

so i need to remove this class,

how can i `$('body').removeClass('ligbox{any}')` ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that's the only class that you set to `<body>`, then remove all the classes

```
$("body").removeClass();

// or
document.body.className = "";
```

If not, go the plain DOM way, use a regular expression to strip the class name out of the string.

```
document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(/\blightbox\d+/, "");
```

The jQuery way is a bit more complicated here:

```
$("body").removeClass(function (index, oldClass) {
   var matches = oldClass.match(/\blightbox\d+/) || [];
   return matches[0];
});
```